# How to produce a 100% Codeception path coverage report?

Tags: xdebug, codeception

I am evaluating Paths coverage and trying to understand how exactly it works. Following are environment details:
Yii2, php-code-coverage 9.2.26 using PHP 8.1.6, Codeception and PHPUnit 9.6.8

Sample php function:

```
    public function checkPaths($a, $b) {
        if($a && $b) {
            echo " Both set! ". $a . " : ". $b;
        }
    }
```

Codeception test:

```
public function testCheckPaths()
{
    $model = new checkPath();

    $a = NULL; $b = NULL;
    expect($model->checkPaths($a, $b));

    $a = NULL; $b = 10;
    expect($model->checkPaths($a, $b));

    $a = 5; $b = NULL;
    expect($model->checkPaths($a, $b));

    $a = 5; $b = 10;
    expect($model->checkPaths($a, $b));
}
```

[Codeception report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrJ2d.png)

[Path coverage report showing on click of blue checkPaths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvRE6.png)

It shows 3 / 4 paths coverage. Please let me know how 100% path coverage can be achieved in this case.

I tried different case combinations in test but not able to achieve 100% path coverage.

Comment: `$model->->checkPaths` looks pretty strange to me. Also, why not click on that blue linked `checkPaths` to see which parts are checked?

Comment: @nicoHaase Thanks for reply. I have fixed typos in code and also uploaded path coverage report that shows on click. I hope it will help.

Comment: What it will show if you add an `else` branch as well? Something like `if($a && $b) { echo " Both set! ". $a . " : ". $b; } else { echo "Nope. At least one is not set!" }`

Comment: As you can see in the second screenshot: some cases are not covered. Try to hover over the red lines to see whether this shows more details

Comment: @LazyOne: Checked with else but no change in Paths. It still shows 3/4 coverage.
NicoHaase: Nothing shows on hover for the red lines.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an interesting one. And it is correct behaviour, although confusing.

When you run the code:

```
$a = NULL;
$b = 10;

if ($a && $b) {
}
```

There is never a check for `$b` done at all, as the `$a` shortcuts the condition. It makes the value of `$b` irrelevant, and hence this means that it is the same test (and path) as when both `$a` and `$b` were NULL, and therefore these both mean the same path.

This means that there is one path out of four that you *logically* can never reach.

Comment: Derick, thank you for reply.
So considering this, is there any way to achieve 100% path coverage in this case?

Comment: No, you can't get 100% path coverage with this code I don't think.